# Stack Overflow in Open Cobol

Tags: gnucobol

I am using Open Cobol.
I have a program that I have been running for several weeks.
Yesterday, I got the following error:

**MERRILL_MAX_AMOUNTS.COB:46: libcob: Stack overflow, possible PERFORM depth exceeded**

I  tried going back to other versions of the same program that worked, but I am still getting the same error. I have several other programs that run fine with no problem.

Comment: Did the provided answer work for you? If yes, then please accept it as answer, otherwise add a comment what is missing concerning your _initial_ question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the program was running for several weeks and then ends with this error the program seems to be broken.

You get that error if a section/paragraph was `PERFORM`ed and then (likely after a bunch of other statements possibly including `GO TO` or `PERFORM`ing other sections/paragraphs there) is `PERFORM' itself again (recursively).
In most cases this is an error.

If the same program "worked before" and now doesn't then its program flow is changed, likely because of different data being processed.

You could enable tracing of paragraphs and sections for this single program by adding `-ftrace` to this single program and adjusting runtime.cfg / export/set `COB_SET_TRACE` and `COB_TRACE_FILE` according to [the runtime documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/code/HEAD/tree/tags/gnucobol-3.1-rc1/config/runtime.cfg#l113).

Note: The `PERFORM` stack checking is only enabled upon request by `-fstack-check`, which is auto-enabled with `--debug` (all runtime checks) or `-g` (debugging) - if you don't want this you can disable it by explicit specifying `-fno-stack-check`.
You can also adjust the number of iterations libcob considers "possibly safe" with `-fstack-size=number`, the current default of 255 is quite high, the maximum that can be set in a current version is 512 (artificial limit only).

In any case I highly suggest to replace the outdated OpenCOBOL (likely 1.1 from Feb 2009) by a current GnuCOBOL version (latest 3.1-rc1 19 days ago).

Comment: The program ran for several weeks with no problems. I went back to several  versions that worked  with no changes and got the same results (STACK OVERFLOW). I am also using the same input file as before. If I go to the about OpenCobol it shows that I am using version 4.7.1.

Comment: @JUNIEMAN there's no OpenCobol version 4.7.1, that's likely the OpenCobolIDE. To see what actualy version of OpenCOBOL/GnuCOBOL you use: preferences [F2]->Compiler ->check.

Comment: @JUNIEMAN I'Ve edited the answer by adding notes about possible tracing to debug the issue you see.

Comment: The version is cobc (GNU Cobol) 1.1.0

Comment: To install the new version, do I have to reinstall the CYGWIN ?

Comment: That's a completely different question. For "more chat-like" you may want to use a discussion board like https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/ - but no, an update from 1.1 to something new doesn't mean you have to reinstall your system; but if you use OCIDE just replace the OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL folder with a current binary from https://arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm.
StackOverflow is all about 1 question and the answers, please see [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).